# Place rectangle without a bounding box centered on a point

Tags: algorithm

I have a bounding box (0 to 100 in both x and y), a point, a width and
a height. The point centers a rectangle given by height and width. How
do I find out where to place the rectangle so it doesn't go out of the
bounding box?

As an example, x = 100, y = 100, height = 20, width = 20. Here, I
should get the coordinates 80/80 here. Same for x=90 and y=90.

I have been told that this problem has been solved, so a link to the
corresponding wikipedia page is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, and with the bounding box being (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), you could do it like this:

```
If x + width / 2 > xmax then x = xmax - width / 2
If y + height / 2 > ymax then y = ymax - height / 2
If x - width / 2 < xmin then x = xmin + width / 2
If y - height / 2 < ymin then y = ymin + height / 2
```

Comment: The `x` you are assigning to - is it a different coordinate than the input `x`?

Comment: I am changing the input x,y to values so that the rectangle fits inside the bounding box. So in this case, the x and y are both input and output. This could be changed by using x1,y1 at the left of the assignments.